# validation with regular expressions in php

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation

I have this code and i do not know why it wont validate. When it find mistake it should display each invalid field that has invalid info, but somehow it shows all the fields invalid. here is my code:

```
<?php
$debug =1;

$fname ="";
$valid_fname = 0;
$fname_regex = '/^([A-Z][a-z]){2,15}$/';
$fname_error = '<span>First name must be 2-15 charachters long.</span>';


$lname = "";
$valid_lname = 0;
$lname_regex = '/^([A-Z][a-z]){2,15}$/';
$lname_error = '<span>Last name must be 2-15 charachters long.</span>';

$phone_number = "";
$valid_phone = 0;
$phone_regex = '/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/';
$phone_error = '<span>Phone number must be xxx-xxx-xxxx format.</span>';

$city = "";
$valid_city = 0;
$city_regex = '/^([A-Z][a-z]){3,20}$/';
$city_error = '<span>City name must be 3-20 charachters.</span> ';

$state = "";
$valid_state = 0;
$state_regex = '/^([A-Z][a-z]){2}$/';
$state_error = '<span>State name must be 2 charachters.</span>';

$error_text = "";
$output_form = 1;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    /*if($debug) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";
    }*/ 
    //debug only

    $fname = trim($_POST['fname']);
    $lname = trim($_POST['lname']);
    $phone_number = trim($_POST['pnumber']);
    $city = trim($_POST['city']);
    $state = trim($_POST['state']);

    if (preg_match($fname_regex, $fname)) {
        $valid_fname =1;
    } else {
        $error_text.= "$fname_error<br>\n\r";
    }

    if (preg_match($lname_regex, $lname)) {
        $valid_lname =1;
    } else {
        $error_text.= "$lname_error<br>\n\r";
    }

    if (preg_match($phone_regex, $phone_number)) {
        $valid_phone =1;

    } else {
        $error_text.= "$phone_error<br>\n\r";
    }

    if (preg_match($city_regex, $city)) {
        $valid_city =1;
    } else {
        $error_text.= "$city_error<br>\n\r";
    }

    if (preg_match($state_regex, $state)) {
        $valid_state =1;
    } else {
        $error_text.= "$state_error<br>\n\r";
    }

if ($valid_fname && $valid_lname && $valid_phone && $valid_city && $valid_state) {
        $output_form = 0;

    } else {
        $error_text .= "<span>Please complete all the fields.</span>";
    }


}//end of if(isset($_POST['submit']))

require_once("./inc/head.inc.php");
```

?>

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <?php require_once("./inc/header.inc.php"); ?>
        <div class="content">
        <?php 
            if($output_form) {
        ?>
            <h3>Please fill out following information.</h3>
            <?= $error_text ?>
            <form class="myform" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
                <p>First Name: <input name="fname" type="text" value="<?= $fname ?>">
                <p>Last Name: <input name="lname" type="text" value="<?= $lname ?>">
                <p>Phone Number <small>(Must be in xxx-xxx-xxxx format)</small><input name="pnumber" type="text" value="<?= $phone_number ?>"></p>
                <p>City:<input name="city" type="text" value="<?= $city ?>"></p>
        <p>State:<input name="state" type="text" value="<?= $state ?>"></p>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
                </div>
            </form>
        <?php
            } else {
        ?>

        <div class="output">
        <h2>Your information is valid:</h2>
        <p>Hello! <?= $fname .' '.$lname?></p>
        <p>Phone: <?= $phone_number ?></p>
        <p>Ciy, State : <?= $city . '' . $state ?></p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php require_once("./inc/footer.inc.php"); ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is not correct. It will search for strings like `AaAsBcDe` (a pair of capital and small character, and 2-15 occurrences of that pair)

Use the following:

```
/^[A-Za-z]{2,15}$/
```

Explanation:

- `^` : Start of the string
- `[A-Za-z]` : Any capital or small letter
- `{2-15}` : 2 to 15 occurances of previous character set
- `$` : End of the string

Similarly you can modify others.

Answer (score 1):

Change the bracket position: 
Example:

```
$fname_regex = '/^([A-Z][a-z]){2,15}$/';
```

to

```
$fname_regex = '/^([A-Z][a-z]{2,15})$/';
```